# how to add item to Spinner's ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, addition, adapter, android-arrayadapter

i had a EditText , a button and a spinner . When click the button , the spinner will add a new item with name you entered in the EditText. But here is the question,  my adapter.add() method seems doesn't work...here is my code:

```
public class Spr extends Activity {
Button bt1;
EditText et;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
Spinner spinner;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bt1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    et = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.et);  
    spinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spr);

    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String temp = et.getText().toString();

            adapter.add(temp);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +
                      parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }});
}
```

}

thanks! ...still waitting

Comment: You definitely don't need to call spinner.setAdapter() again in your View.OnClickListener.  

Your code looks like it should work, though.

Comment: You also don't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Just `adapter.add()` should suffice. When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean?

Comment: i seached the answer ,and someone  tells me ,call notifyDataSetChanged()and setAdapter()again could be help.so i add it,but it still doesn't work...when i run it ,and click the button .it will jump out a error : the application has stopped un expectedly.please try again...(i think the problem is on the method spinner.add(). ) thanks for your help!

Comment: it would help if you could show us the exception shown by logcat at the moment you app crashes.

Comment: there is no exception appears.i tryed : put the items in a ArrayList al , and then adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(... , ... , al ) ...then It works...my question is : what's the difference between them(i mean ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()method and new ArrayAdapter<String>())??   and i'm sorry that my english is so poor,i whish you can understand what i'm saying... thank you so much

Comment: If your app says "the application has stopped unexpectedly", you have an exception.  It's in the log... type adb logcat and then run your code.  Paste the exception here.

Answer (score 15):

When you have created your ArrayAdapter you haven't assigned a resizeable List to it, so when you do add() it cannot increment the size of it and throws a UnsupportedOperationException.

Try something like this:

```
List<CharSequence> planets = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context,
                       R.array.planets_array, planets);
//now you can call adapter.add()
```

You should use a List. With an Array such as CharSequence[] you would get the same UnsupportedOperationException exception.

Answer (score 3):

Javi is right except don't reference an array for the second parameter.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
  someList);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is working as designed, but not as expected.  ArrayAdapter used to only take an array, but the list constructor was added later.  I'm guessing its just doing a toArray() on your list.  This is why you have to either call add on the adapter, or create a new adapter when your List changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an arraylist and copy all recourse to this object then create arrayadaptor and send this arraylist and in onclicklistener of button, add edittext content to arraylist object then call  notifydatasetchanged of adator