# How to change the entry of a spinner in code (Android)

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, android-spinner

Hi I have a spinner for which I would like to change its entry. I have created an array in the values folder. I know that I can edit the entry of the spinner by right clicking on it. But I want to know, how can I change the entry of the spinner using code. I was hoping there would be something like `spinner5.editEntries`

Can someone help please?

Comment: Asked here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505207/how-to-add-item-to-spinners-arrayadapter

Comment: I dont quite get what the equivalent of editng entry is in code

Comment: I just want to add a code checks if a button is pressed. If it is then the spinners entry changes

Comment: Are you looking for the `getStringArray(int id)` method in Resources? Using that you can load the xml-declared array into a `String[]` object, which you can then edit/modify/change to your liking. Do note that you'll probably have to recreate the adapter you're using to populate the Spinner. Alternatively, you might want to convert the array to a List, make the changes on the List object and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter to pick up any changes without reconstructing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Spinner Spinnermiles = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinnermiles);
String [] arrmile ={"5","10","20","30","40","50","70","80","90","100"};
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Searching.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arrmile);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinnermiles.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If you want to change item in spinner at position 3 (which is "30" in example),
 
Set value at that position e.g.

`arrmile[3] = "enter new value you want";`

and after that call

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

then value at that position will be get updated.