# ArrayAdapter for custom layout in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Is it possible to add an adapter to a non-list element (ie. not using ListView)?

For example, I have a LinearLayout where I want to images 3 in a row. Now I would like the view to change when ArrayList content changes. I could not find setAdapter method for anything else except for ListView... But there may be cases when I don't want to use Listview, for example, horizontal or diagonal listing.

Comment: The only other place I've seen ArrayAdapter used (that comes to mind) is with a spinner, see, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505207/how-to-add-item-to-spinners-arrayadapter ... if memory serves, I've seen them in pickers too...

Answer (score 0):

This behavior doesn't seem like it would be tough to imitate with a custom class. Something like:

```
public class UpdatingArray { // or whatever
    private Something[] myArray; // or a list or whatever generic you like
    private mUpdateListener;

    public UpdatingArray(Something[] array){
        myArray = array;
    }

    public void replace(Something something, int index){
        myArray[index] = something;
        update();
    }

    public Something del1stAddLast(Something something){
        Something first = myArray[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++){
            myArray[i] = myArray[i+1];
        }
        myArray[myArray.length - 1] = something;
        update();
        return something; // in case you want it
    }

    // getter(s), if you want them...

    public static abstract class UpdateListener{
        public abstract void onUpdate(Something[] array);
    }

    public void setUpdateListener(UpdateListener) {
        mUpdateListener = listener;
    }

    private void update(){
        this.update(myArray);
    }

    public void update(Something[] array){
        mUpdateListener.onUpdate(array);
    }
}
```

So then in the view:

```
public class CustomView extends View implements UpdateListener {
    UpdatingArray uArray;
    Something[] sArray;

    public CustomView(Context context, Something[] array){
        super(context);
        sArray = array;
        uArray = new UpdatingArray(sArray);
        uArray.setUpdateListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Something[] array){
        sArray = array;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
       // draw your images based on what's in sArray
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have questions. Obviously some of this is psuedo-code.

On the other hand, you could always extend this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html

Or put a private, un-drawn ListView in your custom view and use its methods (composition over inheritance and all that).